# How to create a view using mongo-ruby-driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I want to create a view from a collection. Normally I should use [db.createView](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/) for that, but the method is not defined on `Mongo::Database` in mongo-ruby-driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a view (say `management_feedback`) on a collection (say `survey`):

```rb
client = Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'], database: 'my-db')

client[
  :management_feedback,
  viewOn: 'survey',
  pipeline: [
   { $project: { "management": "$feedback.management", department: 1 } }
  ]
].create
```